# domain of attraction for a Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Let $V$ is a Lyapounov function $V(x,y) = 3x^2 - 2xy + y^2$, $\dot{V}(x,y) = -2(x+1)(x^2+y^2)$. I need to find its domain of attraction.

The minimum of $V$ is $x = -1$, so $\theta (y)$ $ = 3 + 2y + y^2$, min  $\theta$ = 2 and $y = -1$

From here, the domain of attraction is $D = {(x,y): 3x^2 - 2xy + y^2 < 2}$

Also I tried to draw the domain of attraction. Could someone look if I'm doing it right?
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but hardly anything of this makes sense. The minimum of $V$ is $V(0,0)=0$, not “$x=-1$”, and your picture is completely unrelated to the inequality you wrote for $D$. And what is $\theta(y)$?

Comment: As far as I understand since V >0 and V'  < 0, then the equilibrium at x = 0, y = 0 of the system is asymptotically stable. No? Thank you , i just noticed  that image is wrong.

Comment: @HansLundmark () is V(-1,y)

Comment: With the new picture it looks better, but it still sounds completely wrong to say that “the minimum of $V$ is $x=-1$”. Surely that's not really what you're trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Putting in the same plot $V(x,y) > 0$ (black) and $\dot V(x,y) < 0$ (blue) we obtain

[image]

Comment: thank you it looks what i need !